# How to evaluate pre-trained NER model on my domain specific text with stanza (for coreNLP)?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, stanza

I am trying to get F1 scores for the pre-trained English model on my specific text domain without doing any training.

The docs mention the following command:

```
python -m stanza.utils.training.run_ete ${corpus} --score_${split}
```

However as I don't want to do any training, how can I evaluate the model as is?
Also, the format of `${corpus}` is not stated in the docs.

I've got an annotated dataset for my domain in BIO format.